# Backup+format or buy a new SD card?

Tags: memory-card, storage, backup

It's come to the time where my 128GB Samsung Micro SD has only 1% of its capacity left. Given I'm going travelling this summer, I need more memory to shoot.

Is it better for me to buy a USB 1TB HDD, transferring all my photos onto that (they're also stored on my PC so that'll just be a backup) and leaving it to gather dust until my PC dies or my SD card fills up again. I'll format my SD card and use it as new.

...Or should I buy a new 128GB SD card and just use that?

The HDD is only £20 more than the SD card yet is 10 times the capacity. My only worry is if formatting the SD card will shorten it's lifespan or reduce its write speed (my 1300D has a bad enough buffer already!).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the card is failing such that its empty capacity is only 1% of the original? Or do you mean that you've never reformatted the card or otherwise deleted images from it, and now it's full?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How often should memory cards be formatted?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/how-often-should-memory-cards-be-formatted)

Comment: No matter what you choose, **always backup** anything you do not want to lose. Always. No exceptions, no "later". Later you might regret not doing it sooner.

Comment: I hear that washing clothes reduces their lifetime. Given the embarrassment of a wardrobe malfunction, I always buy new clothes instead.

Comment: And using a car reduces its lifetime.  That's why I trade cars once a day.  Too bad I don't have time to do anything else but shop for cars, but that's a small price to pay.  :-D  But seriously, remember the rule of three: if you don't have at least three copies of a file, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What method is best to take backups of your digital photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/292/what-method-is-best-to-take-backups-of-your-digital-photos)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming that the card is just full and you're concerned about the impact of reformatting it and reusing — not that it's failing to the point where the maximum free space is 1% of what it used to be.

Don't worry about formatting. The card is meant for reuse, and even cheap SD cards can go through *hundreds* of write/erase cycles, with higher-end cards rated for many times that. Especially if this is only the *first time* you've ever filled the card, reformatting and reusing is very, very tiny amount of wear.

You note that you're transferring the photos to your PC, you have a backup there — you should also make sure you back up those photos *from* your PC to an off-site location. (Some cloud storage, say.) I'd be a lot more worried about that than about reusing the card.

If you have taken many months to fill up that one card, you *could* decide to just keep it as yet another backup, buy another, and fill it up too. But that's a relatively expensive way to get backups and not necessarily one I'd particularly trust for long-term anyway. Better off reusing the card (as it is designed for) and putting the money towards online backup.

Comment: I don't see why it needs reformatting, either. Just literally delete all the files. This is a trivial filesystem-level operation and takes like 2 seconds. I feel like I must be missing something with this question as it appears to equate to "should I wash this dirty plate, or buy another one?"

Comment: On "format or delete?", see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2673/1943).

Comment: Also related re: format or delete - [Can i do any damage by formatting my memory card to clear it, on a regular basis?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94275/15871) and [What causes an SD card to go corrupt?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40489/15871)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that's more of a workflow thing. I mostly empty my 256GB card to a Western Digital my passport wireless. as I don't always have a computer nearby I just reformat from the camera.

Comment: It's not hundreds of thousands of cycles anymore, it's more on the order of thousands for the best NAND flash, and about 1000 for good NAND. Manufacturers know the average consumer will go through tens of cycles over the life of a card so they build SD cards with the absolute cheapest flash they can find.

Comment: @user71659 Citation needed.

Comment: @mattdm [Panasonic](https://panasonic.net/cns/sdcard/business_sd_j/index.html) (in Japanese, see the chart or click the plus by red 1) claims 250 cycles for normal consumer TLC cards, and 2,000 for professional MLC. This agrees with Sandisk, who rates their [industrial MLC cards](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/669/SanDisk_Industrial%20Grade%20SD%20%20MicroSD%20Product%20Brief-805940.pdf) for 2k cycles, but as far as I can see, will not disclose a number for their consumer line. Working out numbers, consumer [SSD](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/860evo/) are ~700.

Comment: [Panasonic in English](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/system/files/data/download/catalog/id_sd_catalog_e_0.pdf) (top of page 3)

Comment: @lightness I usually use the camera to empty the card, which calls it format. The manual also says to use the camera for it every time, not that I believe that.

Comment: @user71659 I've toned down the language around that.

Comment: @Tim Not necessarily -- if you already have Amazon Prime, you can store unlimited photos to Amazon Cloud Drive. It's true that it will take a long time to transfer, but... better than the alternative!

Comment: @Tim False. My last backblaze B2 bill was 0.95USD for nearly 200Gb of CR2s. With the advantage of no chance of bit rot/loss of files. I upload a day at a time (6Gb ish) instead of letting it pile up, so it doesn't take that long (half an hour, tops).

Answer (score 1):

It is all a matter of what you need. If it takes a 'long' time to fill up the 128Gb SD card then you might buy a new SD card. If you fill it up quickly then the USB HDD is the way to go.

But consider this. If something happens to your camera or SD card then you lose all your pictures. In my opinion you better copy the pictures to a HDD so that they are 'safe' and empty your SD card (you can also put a back-up of important files from your PC on it). It is cheaper and you have your pictures 'outside' your camera. I do not know the price of a 128Gb SD card but I think that it will be more then £20.

Comment: More than £20, from a good brand yes. But not by much. Think £30.

Comment: Always have more than one copy of something, preferably in different continents. Personally, I upload a low res version to google photos, a high res version to flickr and the raw files to backblaze. The first two are free (up to 1tb for flickr) and backblaze costs cents. Last bill was less than 1$/month for almost 200Gb of CR2s.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your workflow. Here's how I'd do it.

- **I'd get an USB HDD anyways**, to keep a backup of the *originals* of my SD card(s) pictures. When travelling, I like to backup on the the photos I shot at the end of the day, and to do it I use a [WD My Passport Pro](http://a.co/2rzesbu) disk, since it has an SD card slot, and it can copy new photos on itself with the push of a single button, without any computer.
- **Later on I download the photos on my laptop** or on my desktop computer for archiving and editing. This way I always have three copies of my shots: one "temporary" on the SD card, one "permanent" on the USB disk, and the one I'm working on on my computer. I don't consider my SD card as a permanent storage device, but just a place where picture stay while they're waiting to be copied to the backup drive and the computer, so I don't need big cards - I use 32 GB cards because I do time lapses, but 16 GB cards would fit nicely in my workflow.
- **When I fill roughly 60%-75%** of the SD card, **and** I've already downloaded the pictures on **both** the HDD and the computer, I format the SD card from my camera. There are two things to keep in mind:

  - When you fill any storage more than 80% it may become slower, at least until you free up some space. I want to avoid this.
  - Actually "basic" formatting writes only a small portion of the storage - it just tells the drive that any memory cell that was previously assigned to data can be used again to store data. You can safely reformat any SD card hundreds of time without any noticeable loss of performance.
- **I usually keep at least 2 SD cards** - as I remove one for copying, I put the other one in the camera. This way there will always be one SD card in you camera, and you won't miss any shot because you forgot to put back in camera the SD card after you put it in your computer reader. It seems a silly problem, but it happens quite often.

One last tip - if I understand it, you are using a micro SD card on a Canon 1300D camera, a camera that fits "full size", normal, SD cards, so I guess you are using an adapter.

Often writing or reading cards in adapters is slower compared to the same operation without any adapter.

You can get a lot better read/write performance from you camera using regular SD cards (they're cheaper too!). Just give them a try.